# MYSQL - LIMIT inside a range

Tags: mysql, select, range, limit

I have built a slider using AJAX for the results, and i have a little problem as follow:

assuming a table with a set of `1 to 15` rows, but, i'm working only with the first 9 rows; in a **1st stage** i  `(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9)` and use the results to build navigation and for displaying the first group.

Then in a **2nd stage** i'm querying theese 9 items, 3 each time from **left** so i `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > '$1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3)` or **right** so i `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < '$1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3)` where `$1` is the last item of each group so `(13 || 11 || 7)` from  `(15, 14, 13) || (12, 11, 10) || (9, 8, 7)`.

Well, immagine to have a representation of above verbose explanation like below:

```
<- [ 15 - 14 - 13 - 12 - 11 - 10 - 9 - 8 - 7 ] ->
   [    15     ]  [    14     ]  [    13     ]
```

Ok, **the problem is** when the "right-query" reach the `last item: 7`, the results-set is `(6, 5, 4)` that obviously is correct but isn't in **our range of 15 to 7**, instead for my purpose it should return nothing. how i can do this with one SQL query?

---

just for sake here is the slider [demo](http://clients.altervista.org/php5/news.php) ( latest item to the right, using the right arrow, is out of range );
*hope it is not too fuzzy question cause i had an hard time figuring out how to explain the problem. ;)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st stage, you can record the minimum id in the returned rows.  Then in your other queries, just add a WHERE condition to make sure the selected ids are greater than or equal to that minimum, for example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <'$1' AND id >='$min' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

in the case where your minimum id is 7 and the "right" query is done with the value 7, it will return nothing.  If I understand your question correctly, this is the behavior you want.

Comment: hey Dan, i couldn't imagine a simpliest solution, thank's for the effort! ;)